# Is there a way to execute code grabbed from input tag in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to experiment with my code and for this reason I wanna build something similar to a CMD prompt on my web page.

I tried `eveal()` knowing about the danger behind this, but i'm building a local application and not a web-app.

This is the type of code I want to end up with:
obviously it doesn't work but is there a way to achieve something like this with just JavaScript?

```js
var prompt = document.getElementById("cmd-prompt");
var prompt_value = prompt.innerHTML;

prompt.onkeyup = function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 13){
    eveal(prompt_value);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<input id="cmd-prompt">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's `.eval()` not .eveal()

Comment: You mention it's a "local" app...you mean this is just for your own use? You know you can just type any JS command into the Console window in your developer tools and it'll execute

Comment: Ok now I stopped understanding this stupid reality... I know abut the developer tools... I wanna know how to build a console myself.

Comment: ok well, as mentioned already, start with correcting eveal() into eval() and see how you get on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, you're trying to get the innerHTML of an input field (which is an empty string) when the document is loaded (when the input doesn't have a value). Try getting the value with `prompt.value` inside the keyup listener instead:

```
var prompt = document.getElementById("cmd-prompt");

prompt.onkeyup = function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 13){
    eval(prompt.value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from StackOverflow.

Comment: The problem wan't just the typo. Answer has been updated.